# How to setup a PPPoE server on VLAN 10 using pppd on osx?

Tags: mac-osx, point-to-point-protocol, pppoe

I'm trying to emulate my ISP setup to configure a few devices remotely before sending it to site. I have a Ubiquiti Edgerouter X that is configured for PPPoE on VLAN 10 using credentials myusername and mypassword.

I'm trying to setup a PPPoE server on my mac using pppd, and how I'm doing that is first statistically setting up a VLAN tagged 10 on the ethernet interface with static IP of 100.100.100.1. I then followed an [osx pppd guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1252/_index.html) to start the server, however I'm getting the following output and the edgerouter is not registering:

```
$ sudo pppd plugin PPPoE.ppp debug nodetach persist holdoff 1 mru 1492 mtu 1492 noproxyarp pppoemode listen 100.100.100.1:100.100.100.2 ms-dns 8.8.8.8

Thu Apr  5 22:24:16 2018 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Thu Apr  5 22:24:16 2018 : publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Thu Apr  5 22:24:16 2018 : PPPoE listening on service '' [access concentrator '']...
```

In my /etc/ppp/pap-secrets file:

```
#client server  secret  ip
myusername  *   "mypassword"    *
```

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is an apple forum that might get to a different user base: https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you have the "server" app: https://www.apple.com/macos/server/

Comment: No I don't have the server app, and a quick read through its features tells me that it doesn't have the ability to setup a PPPoE server.